# C# interface function returning class depending on where it gets implemented

Tags: c#, interface

I would like to have a Interface that depending on what class implements it, a function that the interface declares should return a specific class.

should i use something like this?

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    T returnClassInstance();
}
```

and how should it look when i want to implement it into the classes?

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterFace
{
    public T returnClassInstance()
    {
        ClassInstance class = new ClassInstance();
        return (T)class;
    }    
}
```

What is the best approach to something like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use generics in interfaces -

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    T returnClassInstance();
}
```

And while implementing this interface in class, just use the specific class in generic

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface<ClassInstance>
{
    public ClassInstance returnClassInstance()
    {
        ClassInstance obj = new ClassInstance();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword

Answer (score 2):

Generics

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    T returnClassInstance();
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterFace<ClassInstance>
{
    public ClassInstance returnClassInstance()
    {
        ClassInstance class = new ClassInstance();
        return class;
    }    
}
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword and you might want to use proper naming convention.

Comment: @jga - the variable and method naming were the OP's. So as not to confuse I kept the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it like so:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    T ReturnClassInstance();
}
```

and implement it:

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface<MyClass>
{
    public T ReturnClassInstance()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Class Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern. Here is a good [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/CSharpClassFactory.aspx) about it.